# Flutter InAppwebView ~ How to detect if connection has been lost on page change on iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I have a Flutter App containing an InAppWebView for a page that is written in React. If the user tries to navigate to another page in the InAppWebView while he has no connection, an appropriate reaction should be triggered. On Android, I was easily able to get this to work using the `onProgressChanged` event like this:

```
  void onProgressChanged(InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
    triggerReconnectIfConnectionWasLost();
  }
```

However, on iPhone, this does not work, because the `onProgressChanged` event is not triggered anymore once the website has fully loaded. On Android, this event still triggers every time I navigate to another page. Meanwhile, on iPhone, literally none of the events seem to trigger anymore once the first page has been loaded (I tried onLoadStart, onProgressChanged, onLoadStop, onLoadError, onLoadHttpError, onLoadResource, onLoadResourceCustomScheme, iosOnNavigationResponse (with the useOnNavigationResponse property set in the IOSInAppWebViewOptions) and iosOnWebContentProcessDidTerminate).

I know I could always just run a timer to check the connection in regular time intervals, but that is not really what I want, since the user should be allowed to keep browsing the currently loaded page even if the connection has been lost.

So, does anyone have any idea about how I could get this to work as intended?

Comment: You can listen internet connection with connectivity checker and update ui.